# Hide Pagination using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML

```
<div class = "pagination">
  <ul class = "pagination-wrap>
    <li><a href = "#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The list increases if we have more items. My question is how can I remove lists `<li>` dynamically. For example: if my `totalpages = 1`, I want to remove everything except 1 and so on.

```
totalpages = getpages();   //Returns a number from my function

if(totalpages == 1) {
 $("a:contains('2')").hide();
 $("a:contains('3')").hide();
 $("a:contains('4')").hide();
 $("a:contains('5')").hide();
}
```

Right now I have bunch of if condition like these. Is it possible to do this in one function since I don't want to hard code every scenario. Sort of like: if total pages = 1. exclude 1 and remove everything?

Edit: when totalPages = 3, i want to hide 4 and up but  not 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **jQuery** `:gt(index)` to hide the `<li>` greater than your page count!

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/bevL7/

```
totalpages = getpages();
$(".pagination-wrap li:gt('" + (totalpages-1) + "')").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can hide all and then show only the oune you want

```
function showOnly(someText) {
  $(".pagination-wrap a").hide();
  $(".pagination-wrap a:contains('"+someText+"')").show();
}
```

Comment: When the page number is 3, OP wants to show 1, 2 and 3 but hide 4.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code can't handle pages up from four. It looks like you could benefit from only adding page numbers when needed:

```
var totalPages = getpages();

for (var page = 1; page <= totalPages; page++)
{
    $('ul.pagination-wrap').append('<li><a href="#">' + page + '</a></li>');
}
```

Comment: i am using a plugin which automatically gets the list. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Make below change in to function that hide page number other than get in `getpages()` function is

```
 totalpages = getpages();   
 var list = $(".pagination-wrap li")
 for(var i=0 ;i<list.length;i++ )
 {
     if((i+1)<=totalpages)
         continue;

     $("a:contains('"+(i+1)+"')").parent().hide();
 }
```

May this help you.

Comment: my pagination is being added dynamically by a plugin. so i cant really  change it to add id.